# Photon Perpetual Motion Machine Clarification

Tags: general-relativity, photons, reference-frames, energy-conservation, gravitational-redshift

I recently worked through problem 6.2 in Guidry which had the following setup:

> Take two heights, $z_1$ & $z_2$. You have a gravitational field and a photon propagating vertically in the field between these heights. A device converts the photon into a mass at the top (with 100% efficiency), and at the bottom, it converts the mass back into a photon of equivalent energy. The point is to show that the gravitational redshift of the photon is required for energy conservation to hold in this system.

I completed the exercise, so I'm not looking for a demonstration of this. What I am wondering is why this isn't a problem if we work from the reference frame of the photon. My understanding is that the photon will "say" that there is no redshift (we are saying the photon is the observer in this case), so why wouldn't it also "say" that this is a perpetual motion machine? Then, if it's a perpetual motion machine from any frame, this is problematic since energy conservation must hold in all frames, right? I must be missing something.

Comment: The photon does not *have* a frame where it is at rest.

Comment: how can this be? i see the point that all physics must hold in every reference frame, but if the photon has some consciousness (humor me & pretend), how does it know it's moving but no other object knows it's moving?

Comment: I don't think I, or physics, can answer what a hypothetical conscious photon would know or not know... To address one of the questions in your post though, there cannot be any *massive* observer co-moving with the photon, so no observer would ever measure zero redshift.

Comment: is there some notion of observer that requires mass ? i guess I'm not getting that. i thought it was a hypothetical concept that any frame can be an observer.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber It's not that an observer requires mass to be defined, this is simply a matter of mathematical and physical fact. Massless objects have the exact same velocity (speed of light) at every frame of reference. That is one of the very fundamental axioms of special relativity.

Comment: @rhomaios i dont understand. for every object we see that it sees itself moving at zero velocity. how are these two things not inconsistent. as I said before I understand that you can make the argument "the laws of physics must hold so photon sees itself going at c", but I don't understand how this isn't inconsistent with how we describe all other objects' reference frames. can you please elaborate on this point.

Comment: It is not inconsistent because velocities in special relativity change under Lorentz rather than Galilean transformations. It is in fact mathematically consistent that every massive object may have a reference frame where they are stationary, but massless ones do not. This is explained by the Lorentz velocity transformations.

Comment: @rhomaios im well aware of Lorentz transformations and that things don't transform under Galilean transformations. i still don't get how this answers the question or explains the conceptual misunderstanding. if you arent going to explain or answer the questions I am asking, please don't bother to comment, it's a waste of everyone's time including your own.

Comment: A Lorentz velocity transformation of something moving at the speed of light will always yield $c$. This is tantamount to the fact that you cannot find a reference frame where this velocity becomes 0 (or changes for that matter). The idea that things "feel" themselves as stationary in their own reference frame is the approximate truth and is intuitive, but it just doesn't hold as a fundamental principle. Photons have to "feel" themselves moving even in their own reference frame. It may be conceptually weird and unituitive, but this is how it is.

Comment: @rhomaios okay i have made some progress with this mentally. i have a follow-up now: if we have a frame containing an observer at rest, a ball with velocity $v$ w/rt the frame, and a photon moving in this frame, from the frame of the photon, how fast are the ball and the observer moving? sorry if these questions seem obvious, but they are not to me. i honestly don't even have a guess right now - I just know based on what you said that the photon would say it's moving at c, but I don't know how to describe what the ball and person look like from that POV.

Comment: If you move to the photon's reference frame, things break down and you cannot claim to "see" other objects moving at any velocity. Since physical space in your direction of propagation looks contracted to 0 and time is dilated "infinitely", any "observations" you make in regards to other objects' velocity stop making sense. Again, this is unintuitive, but had you implied that massive objects (in this reference frame) can move at $c$ is a direct contradiction to both the idea that only massless objects move at $c$, and that something moving at $c$ in one frame must do so in every other.

Comment: @rhomaios got it thanks !

Comment: Another way of looking at it: The [_proper time_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) that you would experience on an interstellar journey approaches zero as the speed of your ship approaches the speed of light. We could _informally_ conclude that if you could ride on the back of a photon from where it was created to wherever it was absorbed, then from your point of view, the trip would seem to take zero time. It would seem as if you were instantly teleported from one place to another, and you would have no memory of the "ride" at all. It would be as if the photon never existed.